# Fiware Keyrock Management

Tags: fiware

To use keyrock identity management need to install keystone  in order to get authentication? and how to get single user value by using Get/Users/:id.

By installing oauth and node server.js i can able to login to my fiware login and get the access token this is a correct way for keyrock management implementation in web application.Kindly give guidance for implementation of keystone.

Comment: Keystone is the backend part of keyrock so yes, it is needed to manage authentication. here you will find the API of the component: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-identity-v3.html

Comment: @ÁlvaroAlonso Thanks for the reply  by using oauth2 i can able to redirect the URL and login into the fiware account and get the user info is this right way for using Keyrock management?